# Button display checkbox counter

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a listView with checkBox. When checkBox is checked/unchecked, it will count and display the number in `button` `delete` setText. If the counter is equal to 0, then it will only display `DELETE`, otherwise it will display `DELETE (with the counter)`. But the problem is the delete still setText `DELETE (with the counter)` although the counter is 0.

```
holder.ckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                            int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                            search.get(getPosition).setSelected(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                            checkBoxCounter ++;
                            delete.setText("DELETE"+""+"("+ checkBoxCounter +")");
                        } else
                        {
                            if(checkBoxCounter==0)
                            {
                                delete.setText("DELETE");
                            }
                            else {
                                int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                                search.get(getPosition).setSelected(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                                checkBoxCounter--;
                                delete.setText("DELETE" + "" + "(" + checkBoxCounter + ")");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: @Kathi ya..`private static int checkBoxCounter = 0;`

Comment: @Kathi it still display DELETE(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're never checking for 0. Change the bottom else block to this:

```
else {
   int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
   search.get(getPosition).setSelected(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
   checkBoxCounter--;
   if (checkBoxCounter == 0) {
      delete.setText("DELETE");
   else {
      delete.setText("DELETE" + "" + "(" + checkBoxCounter + ")");
   }
}
```

and remove the earlier check

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this

```
holder.ckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                        int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                        search.get(getPosition).setSelected(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                        checkBoxCounter ++;
                        delete.setText("DELETE"+""+"("+ checkBoxCounter +")");
                    } else
                    {
                        checkBoxCounter--;
                        if(checkBoxCounter==0)
                        {
                            delete.setText("DELETE");
                        }
                        else {
                            int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                            search.get(getPosition).setSelected(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                            delete.setText("DELETE" + "" + "(" + checkBoxCounter + ")");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Hope this works for you!